# expo medialibrary getAlbumsAsync is undefined

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to get access to media albums, and photos using Expo, this is the code I'm using

```
import { MediaLibrary, Permissions } from 'expo'

// I ask permissions
const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL)
this.setState({ permissionsGranted: status === 'granted' }, this.getAlbums)

// if permissions granted
const albumsReponse = await MediaLibrary.getAlbumsAsync()
```

if I try to console.log MediaLibrary, I get undefined,
also I get this error:

[unhandled error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEM6P.jpg)

versions:
expo: 27.0.1
react: 16.2.0
react-native: 0.52.0

Comment: Where exactly is the code where you try to get the media album?